# If $a$ is complex and $n$ is a positive integer, prove that the series converges when $a$ is a positive integer.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, binomial-coefficients

If $a\in\mathbb{C}$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ define
$$\begin{pmatrix}a\\0\end{pmatrix}=1\quad\mbox{and}\quad\begin{pmatrix}a\\n\end{pmatrix}=\frac{a(a-1)\ldots(a-(n-1))}{n!}.$$
It can be shown by induction that the $n$th partial sum of
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\begin{pmatrix}a\\n\end{pmatrix}\quad\mbox{is}\quad(-1)^n\begin{pmatrix}a-1\\n\end{pmatrix}.$$
Use this fact to prove that the series converges if $a\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Essentially, the summation of an alternating series of $a$ choose $n$ has an $n$th partial sum of (-1)^$n$ ($a$-1) choose $n$. I'm given that it works for $a$ as a complex number, but I'm unsure how to prove it when $a$ is a positive integer...

Also, could somebody provide a proof of the partial sum formula? I want to understand how to arrive at it but I keep getting twisted in my induction. Should I attempt to prove by a different method?

Comment: For formatting, [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/307825) might help.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as $n > a-1$ the partial sum is zero, so the sequence of partial sums is eventually constant, hence convergent.

Or just observe that the sum itself is a finite sum. Once $n > a$ the terms all vanish.

Comment: Only if $a$ is an integer. If not, the terms continue non-zero.

Comment: @martycohen  Did you read the question?

Comment: Yes. $a \in \mathbb{C}$, not $\mathbb{Z}$. If $a \not\in \mathbb{Z}$, $\binom{a-1}{n} \ne 0$.

Comment: "Use this fact to prove that the series converges if $a \in \mathbb Z^+$"

Comment: Oh. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to prove the sum.

Suppose that
$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{a}{k}
=(-1)^n\binom{a-1}{n}
$.

For $n=0$ this is
$\binom{a}{0}
=\binom{a-1}{0}
$
which is true since 
both are $1$.

For $n=1$ this is
$\binom{a}{0}-\binom{a}{1}
=-\binom{a-1}{1}
$
which is true since 
both are $-a+1$.

Suppose it is true for $n$.
Then

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} (-1)^k \binom{a}{k}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^k \binom{a}{k}+(-1)^{n+1} \binom{a}{n+1}\\
&=(-1)^n\binom{a-1}{n}+(-1)^{n+1} \binom{a}{n+1}\\
&=(-1)^n(\binom{a-1}{n}-\binom{a}{n+1})\\
&=(-1)^n\left(\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(a-1-k)}{n!}-\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n}(a-k)}{(n+1)!}\right)\\
&=(-1)^n\left(\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(a-(k+1))}{n!}-\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n}(a-k)}{(n+1)!}\right)\\
&=(-1)^n\left(\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}(a-k)}{n!}-\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n}(a-k)}{(n+1)!}\right)\\
&=(-1)^n\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}(a-k)}{(n+1)!}\left(n+1-a\right)\\
&=(-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}(a-k)}{(n+1)!}(a-n-1)\\
&=(-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(a-(k+1))}{(n+1)!}(a-n-1)\\
&=(-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{n}(a-(k+1))}{(n+1)!}\\
&=(-1)^{n+1}\binom{a-1}{n+1}\\
\end{array}
$

and we are done!